# Add click event to custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, click, routed-events

How can I add the Click routed event to my custom class?

This doesn't work. When I click the item the Click event does't occur.

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = ButtonBase.ClickEvent.AddOwner(typeof(HistoryListBoxItem));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control needs to [raise the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx), if you do not do that nothing happens. If you want the whole control to be clickable wrap everything in a button and "forward" its click event.